# Stepwise regression, moderation effects, main effects

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interaction, stepwise-regression

I have a simple model:

$A$ is hypothesized to be a predictor / regressor / explanatory / input variable

$B$ is hypothesized to be the response / regressand / explained / outcome variable

So, the relationship looks something like:

$A\longrightarrow B$

Additionally, $C$ is hypothesized to be a moderator of the relationship between $A$ and $B$.

When I run the regression by including all the variables ("enter" procedure in SPSS), none of the relationships are significant.

When I use "step-wise" regression, and let SPSS choose the variables to include, $C\times A$ has a statistically significant effect on $B$, but SPSS stops the "step-wise" regression procedure before including $A$. I suppose one can assume that $A$ doesn't have a statistically significant effect on $B$ (after the inclusion of $C\times A$ in the model).

Thus, I have a statistically significant moderation term $(C\times A)$ , but the main term $(A)$ has not been included in the model.

What can I do with such a result? I was taught that moderation effects are not valid if main effects were not included in the model. Is there a way around that admonition? Is there some way I could still employ this result profitably?

Comment: `Thus, I have a statistically significant moderation term (C×A), but the main term (A) has not been included in the model.` What SPSS command you use? Linear regression command does not create interactions internally. Did you compute AC youself first and include three variables A, C, AC?

Comment: @ttnphns Yes, I computed AC and included A, C and AC.

Comment: Use entering in blocks. Block1= A C (method enter); Block2= AC (method stepwise or forward). Hereby, you force main effects first. Then, if the prediction allows, the interaction will be added.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to just force the main effects in your model. You should not use step-wise anyhow, see: [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).

Comment: When I use the "enter" method (i.e. not "step-wise), nothing turns up significant. But I see your point, and thank you for the link.

Comment: Did you make sure that the value 0 on both $A$ and $C$ are meaningfull and near the range of the data? For example, if $A$ is year of birth, than the value 0 would be the year 0, which in most cases is way outside the range of the data. In that you would need to center the offending variable(s) before computing $A \times C$.

Comment: I didn't think of centering the data. I just checked my data and I don't think centering will be applicable here. But very good point for the future. Standardization and centering can both be very important. So thank you for reminding me!